# Where can I find a list of PCRE phone number patterns for US numbers?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I am parsing numbers from scraped text stored in my database. The numbers could be in any format such as

```
2125551234
212-555-1234
(212)-555-1234
212*555*1234
two1255five123four
```

etc. and I'd really like to find a list of php regex patterns that I could just throw into an array.
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FOUND IT @ [The Regular Expression Library Website](http://www.regxlib.com)

Comment: Wow it's really nyc stuff!! .